# Storing the results of a prepared statement as a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, create-table, random

**Is it possible to store the result of a prepared table in mysql ?**

*My use case is -*:
I am creating two variables based on certain conditions of the source table, then fetching the randomized rows, based on this criteria.  Since I have 10 of such tables, should I be 1st joining them and then doing this randomization on the "overall" passing/filtering criteria (See also @total below, which is my main criteria, PER table)

```
set @total=(select count(*) from tab_1 where predict_var ="4" or predict_var ="2" ) ;
set @sample= ( select @total*(70/30))  ;

PREPARE STMT FROM " SELECT * FROM tab_1 WHERE predict_var = '4' or predict_var = '2'  union 
(SELECT * FROM tab_1 WHERE predict_var = '0' or predict_var = '1' ORDER BY RAND() limit ?  )" ;
EXECUTE STMT USING @sample;
```

After I have Executed this statement - I want to be storing these rows, for retrieval later, preferably in form of a table. I would like to do something like this

```
# incorrect syntax, but I would like something similar 
create table tab_derived_1
select * from 
EXECUTE STMT USING @sample;
```

Tip : +1 for additionally mentioning, why this does not work with prepared Statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the create table in the statement:

```
PREPARE STMT FROM "CREATE TABLE tab_derived_1 SELECT * FROM tab_1 WHERE predict_var = '4'   or predict_var = '2'  union 
(SELECT * FROM tab_1 WHERE predict_var = '0' or predict_var = '1' ORDER BY RAND() limit ?  )" ;
EXECUTE STMT USING @sample;
```

And if you want to return the results, not just store them in a table, just do a final

```
SELECT * FROM tab_derived_1
```

Comment: Bang on & elegant . I was apprehensive, someone would "throw" stored procedures etc. at me! Wondering why I did not think of this :) Thank you. +1