# Breaking the results of an sql like query into groups by percentiles : In Redshift / postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a collection of group_name with their counts. Say this comes from the statement as below -:

```
--sample input set --
select group_name, count(*) as group_count 
     from mytable group by group_name 
     order by group_count desc ;

    group_name  group_count 
    A 205
    B 200
    C 67
    D 55
    E 50 
    F 12
    and so on..
```

What I want is to organize the results of groups_counts with their group names into 3 groups, say Head, core & tail - **where each group is understood to be in 33% of the total group_count**.So 10, 5 and so on will be replaced by their respective percentiles. And all of this I need to do in redshift(postgres 8.0.2 )

As a first level, it should be something like,

**-- this is not a valid syntax--**

```
select case when group_count  >10 then group_name end ) as Head_group,
case when group_count  >5  and group_count <10 then query end ) as core_group, 
case when group_count  <5   then group_name end ) as tail_group, 
 from 
 ( select group_name, count(*) as group_count 
 from mytable group by group_name 
 order by group_count desc ) ;
```

In the required syntax the selections would be based on sum(group_count) - which will be the total of all group counts. How would I get the same in postgressql , more specifically in Redshift.
Note that **create function is not supported in Redshift**. Also prepare & set is available but not prepare statement in Redshift.

```
   --sample output set---
    Head_group core_group tail_group 
    A           D          F
    B           E
    C
    --Alternative sample output set---
    Head_group 
    A
    B
    C
    core_group 
    D
    E
    tail_group 
    F
```

Note that each group can have a different number of rows returned. 
in **mysql**, I could do something like-:

```
set @total_group_count =(select count(*) from mytable ) ;
set @percentile_group_count = ( select @total_group_count*(30/100))  ;
```

Reference to my related question : 
[Storing the results of a prepared statement as a table in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310085/storing-the-results-of-a-prepared-statement-as-a-table-in-mysql)

Comment: Could you please provide a complete example of a sample input set and a sample desired output set? For example, the output set you have given is clearly not the results of a typical SELECT statement. Could the output be one row per input row, but with an identifier as to which group it would be allocated (head, core, tail)?

Comment: @JohnR Could the output be one row per input row, but with an identifier as to which group it would be allocated (head, core, tail)? -> yes. What I mean is that I need to logically break the groups into 3 sets based on percentiles (ordered by the counts) - the actual results can be 3 rows as a result of 1 statement giving head, core & tail , or 3 statements giving head, core & tail - one per call. All I Need is the actual names of the group_name(s) as the results into each of three logical groups, as above.

Comment: Added the select statment for the 1st result and more visuals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ntile` *window function* is what you most likely want to use here.

It could be used something like this with your query:

```
select group_name, count(*) as group_count,
       ntile(3) over(order by group_count desc) AS group_ntile
     from mytable group by group_name 
     order by group_count desc;
```

That should divide the (descending) value of the `group_count` column into three equal groups. You could then use the `group_ntile` value in you `CASE` statements to do what you want based on which group it's in.

Based on the [*Redshift*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Examples_of_NTILE_WF.html) doc, it does appear that `ntile` is available.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

The argument to `ntile` is the number of ranking groups.

i.e. `ntile` will bucket the results (using the specified *window function* parameters) into the number of groups specified in the argument to the function. So, if you want true *percentiles*, then you should use `ntile(100)`.

Comment: Will ntile ensure that the breakup is by percentiles, given that we use ntile(3) ?

Comment: Got it, Thanks. Do you also want to take a stab at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122670/append-results-from-a-query-to-the-same-result-row-in-postgressql/  - I have troubleshooted this, but it seems to miss something still. Your original answer into 3 groups was correct, I was verifying that the breakup was by the total number of group_names and ordered by group counts thereafter  - which si implicitly percentile !

Comment: In case you are looking at that, please see edit 4, which is where I have gotten as of now.